# How to extract an array in smarty using tpl?

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

Hello guys I have a question about extracting array in Smarty. I know how to use foreach but I have a difficulty in extracting this array.

Here's my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 203
            [category] => Ayala Ave.
            [company_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 291
            [category] => Design
            [company_id] => 2
        )

)
```

In my smarty template I have this

```
{foreach from=$product.category_description item=description1}
    {$description1}
{/foreach}
```

What I need to extract first is the category in index 0 which is Ayala Ave.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can access an array in Smarty with a ".".

```
{foreach from=$product.category_description item=description1}
    {$description1.category}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: @Jerielle Don't forget to refer yourself to the documentation. You'll learn a lot more that way.

Comment: Ok sir I already applied it but it get also the other category which is the design.

Comment: @Jerielle: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/language.variables.tpl#language.variables.assoc.arrays

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{$yourarray[0].category}
```

OR

```
{foreach from=$product.category_description item=description1 name=description1}
   {if $smarty.foreach.description1.first}{$description1.category}{/if}
{/foreach}
```